AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) keeps eating up RAM then becoming unreachable
My EC2 instance as of late keeps running out of RAM, to the point where I cannot even run command anymore, and the instance becomes unreachable, so I end up having to reboot it.
I've run commands such as ps -A --sort -rss -o pid,pmem:40,cmd:500 | head -n 6 | tr -s " " ";z"
And it shows the process that is using the most memory is only taking up 0.7%:

If I run free -h:

Yes I know Linux uses a lot of RAM and this is supposed to be normal, but this can't be the case because my server just stops functioning. I get memory errors when trying to run docker-compose for example.
So how where exactly am I supposed to find what is causing this memory issue? I never had this before

Linux can run in relatively little memory - a t3.nano with 512MB RAM easily runs multiple LAMP stacks. AL2 doesn't have this memory problem, so my guess is it's something you've installed on the instance. How to diagnose it, I'm not sure, that's a question for a Linux guru. Sometimes it's easier to create a new instance than figure out the problem. I use Ubuntu on AWS as there's more community support.
